# Get the last login date for all users in Oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

We have Oracle 11g so the following query didn't work.

```sql
select USERNAME,LAST_LOGIN from dba_users
```

Then I searched and people suggested multiple ways and i got confused. What is the correct way to get the last login date for all users in oracle 11g?

```sql
select username, logon_time
from v$session
```

or

```sql
SELECT
    username,
    timestamp
FROM
    sys.dba_audit_session
```

or

```sql
select username, timestamp
from dba_audit_Trail
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL table records all the actions performed by the user based on level of auditing enforced and it also records login and logoff time of every user which can be identified from action column.

```
 SELECT  MAX(TIMESTAMP), A.USERNAME FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL A WHERE ACTION_NAME = 'LOGON'
    GROUP BY USERNAME ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks! I have tested and the codes seems returned correct results. Do you know how to get info like Last Transaction Date made in a user schema?

Comment: DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL table have plenty of information  based on what level of auditing has been configured, you can get that information from the same table.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select username, last_login
from sys.dba_users;
```

You only need to ask your dba to grant you access to that table.

Comment: the OP already stated that he is using oracle 11, and so last_login is not available. The last_login was not added to dba_users until oracle 12.

Comment: oops.. sorry.. I didn't see that the column was not available. I only looked if the table is available in 11g.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, this is the right way to check the user and their last login date

```
select username, max(logon_time) as logon_time from v$session where username is not null
group by username;
```

Demo

[image]

Comment: Querying from v$session only gets those who are _currently_ logged on.  I seriously doubt that is what the OP wanted.